# Embedding an Excel sheet in an email

Tags: email, microsoft-excel

I'm trying to embed part of an Excel sheet into an email. I tried saving the Excel file as a .HTML and then emailing that, but the .HTML doesn't preserve text colors!  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you save the part you want to send as a new separate Excel file, and then attach it to the e-mail?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: unless the recipient is using the same email software (and maybe even the exact same version on the same operating system, with the same settings), you can never be sure how things look when reading it. (For a lot of technical details see also the Campaign Monitor [Guide to CSS Support in Email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), but your email client might not even be using plain CSS to achieve formatting.)

Comment: Why don't use google docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your options:

- **Use the Windows Snipping Tool**. You can find it in Start Menu > Accessories. Or access it by clicking Start, typing "snipping tool" in the search box and then pressing Enter. After screengrabbing a part of your sheet, it automatically sends it to the clipboard. Open your email client and then just paste it in the body of your message.
- **MS Excel's Camera tool**. To add it to your Quick Access Toolbar, click the MS Office orb > **Excel Options** > **Customize** > Choose **Commands not in the ribbon** from the drop-down menu > Click **Camera** > **Add**. To use it, highlight the cell range you wish to include in your email and then click the Camera tool. Click anywhere in your spreadsheet to drop the image, copy it and then paste it in the body of your email.
- **Copy-pasting cells** - You may lose some formatting (and even merged cells). Or: Paste Special > Source Formatting. You won't lose anything.
- **Create a duplicate spreadsheet** that contains only the values (no formulas) and formatting, and then attach this to your email. I believe recording a macro can help you do this faster.
- **Collaborate online**. Upload it to [Office Live Workspace](http://workspace.officelive.com/en-us/) and collaborate from there. I think you need Office 2010 for this. You can even use Zoho or Google Docs.
- **Use free online file sharing services** like [Dropdo](http://www.dropdo.com), [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), [Box.net](http://www.box.net) or [Min.us](http://www.min.us). Upload then embed the link to your file in your email.

Comment: This was one comprehensive answer sir! :)

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar Thanks! :) But I'm a lady m'lord. :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use Outlook 2007. Can you try to do the following?

1-Go to Insert > Table

2-Excel Spreadsheet

3-Paste your table

4-Make some arrangements like font, color.

I think this solves your problem, at least for now.

Comment: My fault for not being more specific...

I am trying to do this ultimately through my school's online email client (which is pretty crappy), but maybe trying to do it in GMail first would be better. I realize I can attach the file, but that is not what I want. This is starting to sound like a pretty unattainable thing. I actually asked this on Stackoverflow because I want to do it through Python, but they referred me over here...

Answer (score 2):

If your eMail client supports colors and graphics, the answer is copy and paste when the client is in html mode. Another option is to get a different client which will support html. I use Outlook 2003 and [Eudora](http://www.eudora.com/) and both do this without problems.

Comment: This just worked quite well for me with Excel and Outlook 2013 - now to automate it...

Answer (score 1):

This may be clunky, but it seems to satisfy your requirements (as I understand them): have you tried doing a print-screen, pasting the result into MSPaint, cropping it, then pasting the cropped image into the email?  This method guarantees that the email recipient will see exactly what you want them to see, as long as images aren't a problem in your email system.  You can even save a few steps by using the open source [ZScreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/) or some similar print screen utility.  Unless of course the recipient needs to be able to work with the data you're sending, in which case images will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally select anything you need to in your Excel file and then do a copy/paste into a Word document. Save the Word document as a JPEG, go to your "compose mail" button in Gmail and then copy/paste the jpeg into the body. Worked for me.

The format is the only obstacle preventing you from directly copying and pasting your images from Excel to Gmail. Unfortunately Windows isn't exactly up to speed with technology, so it requires that we take the long way around to do anything, but I digress.

Answer (score 0):

First you paste in Outlook & after that copy that Excel data & again paste into Gmail. It work for me check it out, it's cool.

Answer (score 0):

After opening new mail just click on the 'Rich Text' under Format text option. Then select the cursor where you want to embedded the file and just attach the file. It is automatically embedded the file in email.

Comment: But he doesn't want to attach the file.  Just part of it.